# How to push the Second Lower Most Container to be right beneath the Middle Right Container?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn CSS and I have this problem I'm stuck with few hours now. I haven't been to fix it. Can you guys help please?

I want the 'Second Lower Most Container' to stick up to Middle Right Container.

Below is the JSFiddle Link -

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sz2z72xj/)

Below is HTML

```
<body>
        <div class="MainContainer">
            <div class="UpperMostContainer">
                UpperMostContainer
            </div>
            <div class="RightLeftContainers">
                <div class="MiddleLeftContainer">
                    Middle Left Container
                </div>
                <div class="MiddleRightContainer">
                    Middle Right Container
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="LowerMostContainer">
                Lower Most Container
            </div>
            <div class="SecondLowerMostContainer">
                Second Lower most Container
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Below is CSS

```
.MainContainer {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: auto auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.UpperMostContainer {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}

.MiddleLeftContainer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
}

.MiddleRightContainer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}

.LowerMostContainer {
    height: 250px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.SecondLowerMostContainer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: purple;
    clear: right;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: I'd consider using flexbox for this layout.

Comment: I don't mind using flex box but, I'm learning. I want to be able to put this proper without using flex box as well.

Comment: Well its not like using flexbox would be cheating, its a proper way to do this layout. But good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only *proper* solution would be with flexbox - [a-guide-to-flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), anything else would be considered a *hacky* one.

My general advice is to not use negative margins at all. If you're stuck in a situation when there is no other choice, consider changing the whole html structure. You will face a lot of inconsistencies and browser quirks when your structure become complex and many elements depends on each other.

This [article](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) will give you more insights on how to use floats. Clearing the floats gives you this exact behaviour.